# For which $x \in \mathbb{R}$ does this power series converge?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Conclude for which $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the following power series converges:
$$x\ +\ \sum_{k\ \geq \ 2} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2k\ x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}$$

I see a similiarity with the Maclaurin series for $sin(x)$, but there seems to be a factor $2k$ to much in each term.

Would mostly appreciate a hint, but a solution is also acceptable.

Comment: hint: $2k\,x^{2k-1}\,$ is the derivative of ....

Comment: @RaymondManzoni I don't quite see how that helps in this case.

Comment: Your entire expression will thus be the derivative of ... that you may rewrite simply as ... (your idea of the $\sin(x)$ is a part of the solution!)

Comment: (NB: the proposed method allows to find the explicit expression of your series ; concerning convergence use nearly the same proof as for the $\sin$ function)

Comment: (for example https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sine_Function_is_Absolutely_Convergent ). Btw you may provide an answer yourself so excellent continuation (I have to leave...)

Comment: @RaymondManzoni Thank you so much for the help, I think I might finally have solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I might have solved finally solved it. Big thanks to @Raymond Manzoni for great hints and guiding. If you find any errors, please let me know. Here goes:$$x\ +\ \sum_{k\ \geq \ 2} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{2k\ x^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}=\\ x+ \sum_{k\ \geq\ 1} (-1)^k\ (1+(2k+1)) \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\\ -x + \sum_{k \ \geq \ 0} (-1)^k (1+(2k+1)) \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}=\\ -x+\sum_{k \ \geq \ 0} (-1)^k \frac{x^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!} +x\sum_{k \ \geq \ 0} (-1)^k \ \frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}=\\ -x+\sin(x)\ + \ x \ cos(x)=\sin(x)+x \ (\cos(x)-1) \leq 1+2x \text{ which is convergent} \ \forall x $$